# Sending file from Java to Web2py server

Tags: java, file-upload, web2py

How do you send files from a Java desktop app to a Web2py server? 
I'm trying to do this below:

```
StringBuilder mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (byte mByte:Files.readAllBytes(mFile.toPath()))
           mStringBuilder.append(mByte);
```

Then, I send this `mStringBuilder.toString()` via post to Web2py server.

The problem is that I'm not getting the same file back. I cannot decode my  string sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It's simple, you have to use MultipartUtilities class in java to send files to web2py server.